# Will there be a place for example a website or a PPA that holds all the lenses for Unity?

Tags: unity, 11.04, lenses

With the new feature lenses in the Natty Unity launcher will there be a website, ppa or something be created to easily get hold of them so users can browse and install the ones there want?

At the moment there is the default applications, files and folders lenses, but optionally there is two others *at this point*, the [AskUbuntu](https://launchpad.net/askubuntu-lens) and [Gwibber](https://launchpad.net/gwibber/unity-lens-gwibber) lenses each with a separate ppa.

It would be easier if they where all in one place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We at OMG! Ubuntu! are currently building a "visual directory" similar to this for both Lenses and Application indicators that will be available before 11.04 launch.

Comment: Nice!! I read Omg! Ubuntu! regularly and am looking forward to this.

Comment: Has this happened?  I remember seeing a couple articles that listed lenses and indicators, but nothing I would consider a "visual directory" (which would be a really great thing to have).

Answer (score 1):

The place will presumably be the Software Centre.

Lenses are just like any other software in Ubuntu. I would imagine that by Oneiric (11.10) then there will be lots of lenses in the standard repositories that are very easily installable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so..well atleast for now..Simply because you can compare Unity Lenses to that of themes. They customize your desktop experience but they are not essential. Also the fact is they are developed by different authors who would like to maintain their own PPA.

Probably in the future, someone might put together all the lenses under one PPA giving the choice to the users to install which ever one they prefer but that is not going to be official. For example, currently a PPA is being maintained by webupd8 blog owner which has a collection of themes. This is not official but just created to help other users.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: On a sidenote, I really hope someone creates a website which describes the different lenses and also provides a nice interactive website helping new users.